# Determine if ajax request is of type POST or GET in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

For exception handling purposes I would like to know if an ajax request was made with POST or GET, but can't find out how to do it.

I got this far:

```
var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.GetType();
```

Am I on the right track at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `RequestType` property to determine whether it was a GET or a POST.

[`Request.RequestType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requesttype.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod
```

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! I marked the first as accepted only because I couldn't credit both.

Comment: @Darin: +1. Why is there 2 properties for almost similar purpose?

Comment: Or you could just use `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod`